# How to display images with some buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I want to create a page (on my computer) in which the image changes when you click on some buttons on another page on your phone, in a local network. To explain the project, I want the user can choose a word (so, on the phone) and a stain appear on the computer page, so it will create a shading overtime. (It's important because it means images will superimpose themselves).
I'm totally new in programming so it's a very hard work for me.

However i'm now able to communicate between my phone and my computer by a local network by using socket.io and node.js . I'm able too to make the things I want in a simple html page. But I absolutely don't know how to make the same thing with the socket.io. That's why I need your help. For the fact that I want two pages which are different and communicate I think I know in what direction I must go, but the real problem is with buttons that display images.
**EDIT :** Moreover, I want image appear with a fade

my server.js file

```
io.socket.on('connection', function(socket) {
      console.log('Client connected...');
      //when the server receives clicked message, do     this
    socket.on('clicked', function(data) {
          clickCount++;
         //send a message to ALL connected clients
      socket.broadcast.emit('buttonUpdate', clickCount);
    });
});
```

and index.html

```
<p id="buttonCount">The button has been clicked 0 times.</p>
<button onclick="buttonClicked()">Click me</button>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
             var socket = io.connect();

             function buttonClicked(){
               socket.emit('clicked');
             }

             //when we receive buttonUpdate, do this
             socket.on('buttonUpdate', function(data){
                 document.getElementById("buttonCount").innerHTML = 'The button has been clicked ' + data + ' times.';
             });
        </script>
```

I know the important part of my actually code is here, even if that has actually nothing to do with that I want.

And in html langage I usually simply use a function like this

```
".titre" ).click(function() {
  $( ".d5" ).fadeIn( 2000 );
  $( ".d4" ).fadeIn( 2000 );
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you flip the code of your file like `io.socket.on()` should be from server.js and vice versa. Does the number of button persist over multiple sessions or does it only apply to browsers that have the page opened?

Comment: Sorry for the unprecision but for the first part of your comment it’s ok aha! I made an error in the post, sorry. I don’t really understand the question, I want only the sender on his phone can use buttons. I only need two pages, one the phone and one one the computer, and if just one person can use it it’s ok. (I think the second choice is ok)

Answer (score 0):

`socket.broadcast.emit()` will emit the event to everyone **EXCEPT** the client who invoked the current event.

`socket.emit()` will emit to the client only.

With that said, you need to do both in order to reach everyone.

```
io.socket.on("connection", function(socket) {
  console.log("Client connected...");

  // On emit from client with socket.emit("clicked")
  socket.on("clicked", function(data) {
    clickCount++;

    // Emit from server to client
    socket.broadcast.emit("buttonUpdate", clickCount);
    socket.emit("buttonUpdate", clickCount);
  });
});
```

See [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/6yq3738mrn) for example.

- `https://6yq3738mrn.sse.codesandbox.io/` for the main page that only display the number.
- `https://6yq3738mrn.sse.codesandbox.io/control` for the control page with the button.

Comment: 0


Thank you for your answer, Maybe I didn't explain correctly what I want, but it's a code that I used to learn Javascript and socket.io and it looked like almost what I wanted. But now I want to display image with the button (in a different page as buttons)

Comment: @CyrilKimmerlin I'm sorry but to be honest, I don't quite get what exactly you want achieved.

Comment: Forget the numbers, I want to display an image on main page when you click on the button on the control page :) . And this with something like 10 buttons and 10 images which correspond to each buttons. Is it more clear?

Comment: @CyrilKimmerlin Updated the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/6yq3738mrn) to include something like that. How you manipulate DOM is still the same. You just have to pay attention to how to trigger your code with socket.io.